# detecting right mouse double click with Bing maps

Tags: bing-maps

I don't see an event in the Bing map API v7 that will surface a double click event.  Is there a way to do this?  Assuming there isn't native support that I missed, I think I will have to write my own double click handler with a timer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had also a problem with the click-events. In facts, the normal click-event also fires during a double-click event. That is why I had to implement my own double-click handler. My approach can be translated to the rigth click, because I am only using the single-click event, which is also available for the right mouse button.

```
//Set up my Handler (of course every object can be the target)
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'click', Click);
//count variable, that counts the amount of clicks that belong together
myClick=0;

//A click fires this function
function click (e)
{
    //If it is the first click of a "series", than start the timeout after which the clicks are handled
    if (myClick == 0)
    {       
        //Target have to be buffered
        target= e;
        //accumulate the clicks for 200ms and react afterwards
        setTimeout("reaction(target)", 200);
    }
        //count the clicks
    myClick = myClick+1;
}

//At the end of timeout check how often a click has been performed and react
function reaction(e)
{
    if (myClick==1)
    {
        alert("Single Click!");
    }
    else (myClick==2)
    {
        alert("Double click!");
    }
        else (myClick==3)
        {
                alert("Tripple click");
        }
    //reset ClickCount to zero for the next clicks
    myClick = 0;
}
```

Moreover it might be interesting to remove the standart double-click behaviour of Bing-Maps, to zoom in. This can be realized by the following code:

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'dblclick', function(e){
      e.handled = true;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

If you only use double click event

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(this.map, 'dblclick', functionHandler)
```

should solve the problem